# Go to a specific fragment from anywhere keeping backstack

Tags: android

I'm updating the old navigation system from my app to jetpack navigation and I'm facing an issue:

From a DialogFragment which can be displayed from almost any fragment in the app, I have a button which leads to a specific Fragment. I've found in the documentation global actions, but it seems they clear the entire navigation backstack when you navigate with one of these and I need to keep my backstack, just add this new fragment to it from anywhere. What's the solution to this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: If it leads to a specific Fragment you should be able to navigation to that fragment without an action.  navController.navigate(R.id.yourfragment, bundle).

Comment: @KristyWelsh Perfect, thanks, I thought it was mandatory to create actions. But without an action, is it possible to use animations between fragment?

Comment: it is, you can write a kotlin extension (navcontroller) to do this.

Comment: Global actions are about *scope* - they can be called from anywhere within that graph. They do not clear the back stack unless you specifically add the `popUpTo` attributes to do that. What makes you think they do anything other than exactly what the action says?

Comment: @ianhanniballake You're right, I tried again and it works as expected. I probably checked something wrong. Thanks